# Merging two SQL SELECT statements

Tags: sql, select, merge

I need to merge two SELECT statements.

There are two tables in my database, where table A consists of two fields; Type and Counter. Table B consists of two fields; Source and destination.

```
Table A has three items; 
                   { 1, 5000 }, { 2, 10000 } and { 3, 15000 }. ({Type, Counter})
Table B has two items; 
                   { 5000, 10000 } and { 10000, 150000 }. ({Source, Destination})
```

That is, table B's values consist of data from table A.

The data I have available for my query are Type in table A (1, 2 and 3).

The end result of a query (the one I'm after) to the database should be one item; { 5000, 10000, 15000 }, where columns should read {Source, Middle, Destination}, respectively. However, I've been unable to create a query that can appear in such format.

I am able to get the data using an INNER JOIN, where the result appear as two items; { 5000, 10000 } and { 10000, 15000 }. (Not simply the content of table B that is, if the tables would consist of other items, as well.)

(There's obviously far more items in both tables than I've displayed above.)

So, how can I write the SQL query to make my result appear as { 5000, 10000, 15000 } (with appropriate column names)?

Comment: Can you post the select statement you have tried?

Comment: Is there only ever a middle? Or could your "path" go 5000 -> 10000 -> 15000 -> 20000 -> 25000? In which case what would your columns look like?

Comment: There is one middle.
The following is my (incorrect SELECT);
SELECT  *
                    FROM    TableB INNER JOIN
                            TableA TD1 ON TableB.SourceType = TB1.Type INNER JOIN
                            TableA TD2 ON TableB.DestinationType = TD2.Type         INNER JOIN
                            TableA TD3 ON TableB.DestinationType = TD3.Type       INNER JOIN
                            TableA TD4 ON TableB.DestinationType = TD4.Type
                    WHERE   TD1.Counter=5000 AND TD2.Counter=10000 OR TD1.Counter=10000 AND TD3.counter = 15000

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what you are looking for. I fail to understand what you are actually trying to achieve. You clearly aren't just looking to join the tables. Are you looking to retrieve the lowest source, the highest destination and a value in the middle?

Comment: The values can be anything, only that each number is unique.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking you just want the result to output three values? If so, please explain how the SQL should decide which values to output, as I don't understand what it is you want from the SQL query.

Comment: See below for the correct queruy by Kirk. (How could I have formulated my question so it would've been more clear? For future reference, I mean..)

Comment: The question was clear, but I think that it initially seemed there might be more to it because you mentioned Table A and it's relevance was not immediately clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, you don't have any use or need for table A - you are simply joining Table B to itself on Source = Destination.

Your query should be

```
SELECT a.Source, a.Destination, b.Destination
FROM [Table B] as a INNER JOIN [Table B] as b
ON a.Destination = b.Source
```

Comment: That seemed to have done it. Thanks. I guess I was staring blind that I needed to have any input, but apparantly not.

Comment: I posted a correct answer, why did you vote it down?  I posted it before I saw yours, and I like mine better.